# Biblatex & Biber in TexStudio on Windows - Central Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, texlive, texstudio, biber, database

## Introduction

I have a TeX file that contains a number of references built using TeXStudio on Windows 10 using TeXLive as a backend. Since migrating from BibTeX to BibLaTeX/Biber I haven't been able to access my centralized `library.bib` file located in `$TEXMFLOCAL`.

I previously used standard BibTeX to retireve references stored in a centralized/database bibliography created by [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/) in the BibTeX format. This library is located at `$TEXMFLOCAL/bibtex/bib/local/library.bib` (which translates to `D:\Dev\texlive\texmf-local\bibtex\bib\local\library.bib` on my system)

### Current Software

- Mendeley 1.16
- TeXLive 2015
- TeXStudio 2.10.8

### Compile Sequence

pdfLatex -> BibTeX/Biber (as appropriate) -> pdfLatex -> pdfLatex

Whilst debugging this problem, I have also been clearing the auxiliary files and compiling from scratch to eliminate any potential issues with corrupt files.

## BibTeX MWE

With BibTeX, I can access this library using:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for MWE

\begin{document}
  \section{Some Title}
    \lipsum[2]
  \section{Another Title}
    \lipsum[2]
    \par Summarised point \cite{TheRef2016}
  \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
  \bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```

## BibLaTeX MWE (BibTeX Backend)

This example functions as inteded by still uses BibTeX as the backend.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for MWE
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}

\begin{document}
  \section{Some Title}
    \lipsum[2]
  \section{Another Title}
    \lipsum[2]
    \par Some text here \cite{TheRef2016}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

## BibLaTeX MWE (Biber backend)

A `.bib` file located in the same directory works fine as demonstrated by the MWE on the wiki ([MWEB (for BibLaTeX) - Tex.SE Wiki](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/101341)).

However, adjusting it to use the centralized bibliography as before results in an error message saying that the bibliography file cannot be found.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for MWE
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib} % Also tried with \bibliography{library.bib}

\begin{document}
  \section{Some Title}
    \lipsum[2]
  \section{Another Title}
    \lipsum[2]
    \par Some reference \cite{TheRef2016}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

These are the error messages given when compiling with Biber:

```
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'library.bib' for section 0
ERROR - Cannot find 'library.bib'!
```

## Conclusion

I'm probably missing something fundamental but have been stumped by this problem for the past couple of hours with no luck in finding a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you moved the file up one directory.

Comment: Does it also happen, if you run the commands from the command line?

Comment: @jon - Moving it up one directory didn't solve the issue.
@TimHoffmann - Running it from the command line also results in the file not found message. Currently the only work around I am using is to explicitly declare Biber's ``--input-directory`` parameter as ``--input-directory=D:\Dev\texlive\texmf-local\bibtex\bib\local``. Which seems counterproductive as this is on the standard BibTex search path.

Comment: How odd.  Wish I had a good hint, but I'm on Linux. Last time I used LaTeX on Windows (on my own machine) Biber was not yet invented....